# Cron Job on dreamhost server

Tags: php, cron, dreamhost

I am trying to run a script not hosted on dreamhost control panel cron job. I have tried in 2 seperate cron jobs:

```
wget -q -O /dev/null http://othersite.com/api/script.php
```

-and-

```
/usr/local/php56/bin/php "http://othersite.com/api/script.php"
```

With the later outputting an error message:

```
Could not open input file: http://othersite.com/api/script.php
```

Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: try to give the base path not the url path

Comment: it isn't on the server so I have to use the url unfortunetly

Comment: could I run this outside script, inside of a server-side php file? For example: server.php runs `http://othersite.com/api/script.php`

Comment: the why don't you use the curl instead of php ?  @davefromcamp

Comment: I just tried `curl --silent http://othersite.com/api/script.php`  without success. Any other thoughts?

Comment: update the question with the output you get from trying curl... and the exact output you get from wget, too, while you're at it. And to be sure, you're issuing these commands from ssh-ing into a shared hosting machine, right?

Comment: ohk then another way is make a php file in your hosting space then make a curl call to that particular file using the php CURL and get the response in the mail to check whether it is working or not.? @davefromcamp